# Laravel use vendor directory php class

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I learn Laravel and try to implement BingAds SDK to grab some reports to my database but failed.

I have a controller named BingAdController.php in app/http/Controllers/BingAdController.php

BingAds SDK is installed via composer, they are in vendor/microsoft/bingads/samples/V12/ReportRequests.php

BingAdController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use SoapVar;
use SoapFault;
use Exception;
use SoapClient;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\BingAd;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Microsoft\BingAds\V12\Reporting\ReportRequestStatusType;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClient;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClientType;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Samples\V12\AuthHelper;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Samples\V12\ReportRequestLibrary;

include("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/microsoft/bingads/samples/V12/ReportRequests.php");

class BingAdController extends Controller {
    public function bingadsReporting(){
```

ReportRequests.php

```
namespace Microsoft\BingAds\Samples\V12;

// require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/autoload.php";

include __DIR__ . "/AuthHelper.php";
include __DIR__ . "/ReportRequestLibrary.php";

use SoapVar;
use SoapFault;
use Exception;

use Microsoft\BingAds\V12\Reporting\ReportRequestStatusType;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClient;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Auth\ServiceClientType;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Samples\V12\AuthHelper;
use Microsoft\BingAds\Samples\V12\ReportRequestLibrary;

$GLOBALS['AuthorizationData'] = null;
$GLOBALS['Proxy'] = null;
$GLOBALS['CampaignManagementProxy'] = null; 

class ReportRequests {

    public $DownloadPath, $length, $folder;
```

Laravel keep saying the class not found...
I have been stuck in this problem for 2 days... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Add "vendor/microsoft/bingads" into vendor/composer.json -> classmap

Don't know why BingAds didn't auto update composer.json even via composer install.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be manually calling `include` or `require_once` in your code - Laravel uses Composer's autoloader out of the box, so you should just be able to refer to the classes you need and it will do the rest.

First, ensure that you have installed Bing's SDK through Composer - i.e. it's added in your `composer.json` and it was installed through the command line tool. If you just downloaded it yourself and dropped it in the `vendor` directory it's not going to work.

Then you should be able to call `new Microsoft\BindAds\Auth\ServiceClient` or whichever class you want - Composer will know where and how to find this class for you.

If you have installed it through Composer and are still having issues you'll need to provide the exact code you're having issues with as well as the full error and stacktrace you're seeing so that we can assist debugging it.

Comment: I installed the sdk through Composer.

Comment: still Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Microsoft\BindAds\Auth\ServiceClient' not found.
Is it possible because both php file have a namespace?
If yes, I can't add a extra namespace in my BingAdController.php.

Comment: You will need to add `use Microsoft\BindAds\Auth\ServiceClient` to the top of your file, so that it will know to look for the class in the right place. Otherwise it will look for the class relative to the current namespace (`App\Http\Controllers`).

Comment: use Microsoft\BindAds\Auth\ServiceClient;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
still got class not found :-(

Comment: The use statement should be going after the namespace statement. You might need to do more reading on how namespaces work in PHP.